# CSV: extract second column and save as new file with filename from first column

Tags: bash, unix, csv, sed, awk

I have **one** CSV file `master.csv`:

```
AA,"Today is hot"
AA,"Tomorrow will rain"
BB,"Snowing on Tuesday"
CC,"Thunderstorm last week"
CC,"Yesterday was sunny"
```

I would like to extract 2nd column contents and save them to a new file with column1 as the filename.

Desired output:

```
AA.txt
Today is hot
Tomorrow will rain

BB.txt
Snowing on Tuesday

CC.txt
Thunderstorm last week
Yesterday was sunny
```

Is there a handy awk or sed one-liner that can do this?  I'm trying a while loop in bash right now but it's getting kind of unwieldy.  Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=, read -r filename string; do
    string=${string#\"}
    echo "${string%\"}" >> "$filename.txt"
done <<END
AA,"Today is hot"
AA,"Tomorrow will rain"
BB,"a string \"with, inner\" quotes"
BB,"Snowing on Tuesday"
CC,"Thunderstorm last week"
CC,"Yesterday was sunny"
END

more {AA,BB,CC}.txt
```

```
::::::::::::::
AA.txt
::::::::::::::
Today is hot
Tomorrow will rain
::::::::::::::
BB.txt
::::::::::::::
a string \"with, inner\" quotes
Snowing on Tuesday
::::::::::::::
CC.txt
::::::::::::::
Thunderstorm last week
Yesterday was sunny
```

Answer (score 1):

using awk

```
awk -F "[,\"]" '{print $3 > $1 ".txt"}' file
```

Comment: Hope that you don't have a comma in the quoted string.

Comment: Agree, but we needn't guess that if there is no that request at all. Unless OP meantions it.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -e '
    $csv=Text::CSV_XS->new();
    while (my $row=$csv->getline(ARGV)) {
        system qq(echo "$$row[1]" >>"$$row[0].txt")
    }
' master.csv
```

or more secure

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -E '
    $csv=Text::CSV_XS->new();
    while (my $row=$csv->getline(ARGV)) {
        open my$f,">>",$row->[0].".txt" or die $!;
        say $f $row->[1];
        close $f;
    }
' master.csv
```

Comment: In the 2nd version, you could keep a hash of filehandles so that you only have to close them outside the while loop, and you could test the existence of the hash key to see if the fh is already open.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yep, it would be far faster but it will be more complicated and you can run into problem with open file-handles limitation which makes solution less solid. BTW first solution behaves in same way as second one and also all other solutions in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

My version of `awk`, in case there is comma inside quoted string

```
awk -F "\"" '{print $2 > gensub(/,/, "", "g",$1)".txt"}' master.csv
```

use `"` as the separator
remove any `,` in `$1` and send the content of `$2` to the `.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 's/([^,]*),(.*)/echo \2 >>\1.txt/e' file
```